# show current add data Dropdownlist without Refresh Entire Page in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to Bind Dropdownlist , with which are added current data without relaod entire page 
For Example : 
one Textbox and one button and one dropdownlist.
enter text in textbox and hit on the button then, that value show in dropdownlist without reload entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire a jQuery onclick event on your button click which will call a controller from mvc and return you the list in response in the jQuery function. After getting response render your dropdown list using for loop. Here putting the code by which i was able to do it.

```
function AddPlayer()
{
    //debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/Home/GetPlayers",
        data: { tid: $('#ddlState').val() },
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (res) {
            var player = "<select id='ddlPlayer' class='form-control' 
            onchange='DuplicatePlayer()'>";
            player = player + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
             {
                player = player + '<option value=' + res[i].Value + '>' + res[i].Text 
                + '</option>';
             }
            player = player + '</select>';
            $('#PlayerID').html(player);
        }
    });

}
```

In var player , we are writing a html code as a string with loops and finally assigning it to a | id which renders our dropdownlist in html `<div>` having that Id.

Comment: This does add the text to the dropdown (which is what the OP asked for), but will not update any server-side database (which was not asked for but will probably be the next question)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Any which ways we are just retreiving data , Controller will call database  SPs using repository or SQLHelper class or Using entity Framework. we have no need to update the database. and talking about serverside database , if i click the button 1000s of time , are you going to update server side DB 1000s of time. so i basically preferto just add text to the DropdownList

Comment: Just beware that that dropdownlist exists only in the browser until you refresh the page. But that may be enough.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing , Exactly and thats what he wants , load list on some button click